# Regular Expression: replace the n-th occurence

Tags: r

does someone know how to find the n-th occurcence of a string within an expression and how to replace it by regular expression?

for example I have the following string

```
txt <- "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa"
```

and I want to replace the 5th occurence of '-' by  '|' 
and the 7th occurence of '-' by "||" like

```
[1] aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa|aaa-aaa||aaa-aaa-aaa
```

How do I do this?

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(1) sub** It can be done in a single regular expression with `sub`:

```
> sub("(^(.*?-){4}.*?)-(.*?-.*?)-", "\\1|\\3||", txt, perl = TRUE)
[1] "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa|aaa-aaa||aaa-aaa-aaa"
```

**(2) sub twice** or this variation which calls `sub` twice:

```
> txt2 <- sub("(^(.*?-){6}.*?)-", "\\1|", txt, perl = TRUE)
> sub("(^(.*?-){4}.*?)-", "\\1||", txt2, perl = TRUE)
[1] "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa|aaa-aaa||aaa-aaa-aaa"
```

**(3) sub.fun** or this variation which creates a function `sub.fun` which does one substitute.  it makes use of `fn$` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) to substitute `n-1`, `pat`, and `value` into the `sub` arguments.  First define the indicated function and then call it twice.

```
library(gsubfn)
sub.fun <- function(x, pat, n, value) {
   fn$sub( "(^(.*?-){`n-1`}.*?)$pat", "\\1$value", x, perl = TRUE)
}

> sub.fun(sub.fun(txt, "-", 7, "||"), "-", 5, "|")
[1] "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa|aaa-aaa||aaa-aaa-aaa"
```

(We could have modified the arguments to `sub` in the body of `sub.fun` using `paste` or `sprintf` to give a base R solution but at the expense of some additional verbosity.)

This can be reformulated as a replacement function giving this pleasing sequence:

```
"sub.fun<-" <- sub.fun
tt <- txt # make a copy so that we preserve the input txt
sub.fun(tt, "-", 7) <- "||"
sub.fun(tt, "-", 5) <- "|"

> tt
[1] "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa|aaa-aaa||aaa-aaa-aaa"
```

**(4) gsubfn** Using `gsubfn` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) we can use a particularly simple regular expression (its just `"-"`) and the code has quite a straight forward structure.  We perform the substitution via a proto method.  The proto object containing the method is passed in place of a replacement string.  The simplicity of this approach derives fron the fact that `gsubfn` automatically makes a `count` variable available to such methods:

```
library(gsubfn) # gsubfn also pulls in proto
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) {
     if (count == 5) return("|")
     if (count == 7) return("||")
     x
 })

> gsubfn("-", p, txt)
[1] "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa|aaa-aaa||aaa-aaa-aaa"
```

UPDATE: Some corrections.

UPDATE 2: Added a replacement function approach to (3).

UPDATE 3: Added `pat` argument to `sub.fun`.

Comment: Great, quite a lot possibilties! Thanks, Florian

Answer (score 4):

An alternative possibility is using Hadley's `stringr` package which builds the basis for the function I wrote:

```
require(stringr)

replace.nth <- function(string, pattern, replacement, n) {
    locations <- str_locate_all(string, pattern)
    str_sub(string, locations[[1]][n, 1], locations[[1]][n, 2]) <- replacement
    string
}

txt <- "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa"

txt.new <- replace.nth(txt, "-", "|", 5)
txt.new <- replace.nth(txt.new, "-", "||", 7)
txt.new
# [1] "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa|aaa-aaa-aaa||aaa-aaa"
```

Comment: @Henrik, I think there is a slight error with your solution. As you can see from your output the 8th "-" from the original series is changed and NOT the 7th as intended. You have to change the 2 lines so that you start with the line that changes the 7th "-" to "||", otherwise one of the "-" has already been changed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `gregexpr` to find the positions of the `-`:

```
posns <- gregexpr("-",txt)[[1]]
```

And then pasting together the relevant pieces and separators:

```
paste0(substr(txt,1,posns[5]-1),"|",substr(txt,posns[5]+1,posns[7]-1),"||",substr(txt,posns[7]+1,nchar(txt)))
[1] "aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa|aaa-aaa||aaa-aaa-aaa"
```